# HTML changes not reflecting on website in Django app using Ubuntu 20.0, Nginx, and Gunicorn

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm hosting my Django website with Digital Ocean using Ubuntu 20.0. I deployed my app successfully. I have now been making changes to my HTML files. After running git pull origin master, I restarted both Gunicorn and Nginx. The changes are reflected in development but not in production. What could be the problem?

Comment: have you tried `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` ?

Comment: Yes, I started with sudo systemctl daemon-reload then sudo systemctl restart gunicorn, and finally sudo service nginx restart

Comment: Try finding a file you know has changed in your source code and `sudo nano` it to ensure that the pull was successful.

Comment: The pull was successful according to my Server IP via Port 8000.

Comment: I had three django apps: members, ablog, bidding. When I run find . only members and ablog can be find in the server. the bididing app is missing hence I cannot sudo nano the changed template